# Find encoding of character using binary sequence

Tags: java, character-encoding, xstream

I encountered in an XML the following text:

```
<name>21&#x19;&amp;ª</name>
```

There has been an encoding issue which led to the text `21"` to become these characters. Note that I typed the double quote here using my keyboard but in reality it's probably one of those microsoft word auto replaced double quotes. I have broken down these weird characters into the following bytes using UTF-8, because that is what my Java code's Xstream library does:

- `&#x19;` = 00011001
- `&amp;` = 00100110
- ª = `&ordf;` = 11000010 10101010

So in total the weird double quote character somehow resulted in these bytes:

```
00011001 00100110 11000010 10101010
```

Using all this knowledge, I would like know to find the encoding and the original character that was being given as input to our system. In other words, which non-utf8 character resulted in that byte sequence? Which encoding do I need to convert those bytes back to the original character? I tried some online converters but they all assume ascci or UTf-8 and don't let me set different encodings for me try.

Comment: Does this have to be in Java? You might be able to use something like ftfy (https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see what's going on.

Comment: Well, the ftfy program kind of does what I want to do (detect weird sequences of characters and replace it with a more standard character), but yes it should be Java. Is this program's source code available?

Comment: source is here: https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy